# Android Studio is opening xml files in notepad

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, intellij-idea

I am using Android Studio on windows.

Everything was going fine until I added a new xml file, but accidentally changed the file extension to .xm instead of .xml. Then I clicked on a prompt that I received without realizing that it would affect my whole project. Now, all the xml files are opening in notepad (my default System editor).

Anyways, how can I restore Android Studio to the point where my xml files would open in Android Studio instead of notepad?

**Edit**: I can see and edit the xml files, but in notepad instead of in the Android IDE itself. This includes, AndroidManifest, Colors, Strings, Layouts, etc.

Comment: If you cant find out then just drag and drop them on Android Studio.

Comment: Yes i know. You already told that. But you are not doing what i said you to do. Please reread and try. Dont click them! Drag and drop them.

Comment: And what possibilities are there in the context menu? When you right click?

Comment: Just to clarify, this happened when you added a new file, and not when you refactored an old file, right?

Comment: @greenapps I can only view it, it won't let me edit, and what you gave me is a workaround, if anything

Comment: @Juliette_Evans yes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to Setting -> Editor -> File Types -> Files Opened In Associated Applications and removed *.xml then add it to Setting -> Editor -> File Types -> XML